# How to calculate $\int \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}dx$?

Tags: integration

I am trying really hard but cannot figure out how to calculate the following integral:

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}dx.$$

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Among the options: If you substitute $u = \sqrt{1+x^2}$, then $x = \sqrt{u^2-1}$ and $dx = \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2-1}} \, du$.  Then you wind up with an integral that can be done by partial fractions.

Comment: This is not a ["good" question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it. +1 however, for recalling the simplest (and standard) method.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Substitute $x=\tan(u)$ and $\text{d}x=\sec^2(u)\space\text{d}u$.

Then $\sqrt{1+x^2}=\sqrt{1+\tan^2(u)}=\sec(u)$ and $u=\arctan(x)$:

---

$$\int\csc(u)\sec^2(u)\space\text{d}u=\int\left(\tan^2(u)+1\right)\csc(u)\space\text{d}u=\int\left(\csc(u)+\tan(u)\sec(u)\right)\space\text{d}u=$$
$$\int\csc(u)\space\text{d}u+\int\tan(u)\sec(u)\space\text{d}u=\int\csc(u)\space\text{d}u+\int\frac{\sin(u)}{\cos^2(u)}\space\text{d}u=$$

---

Substitute $s=\cos(u)$ and $\text{d}s=-\sin(u)\space\text{d}u$:

---

$$\int\csc(u)\space\text{d}u-\int\frac{1}{s^2}\space\text{d}s=\int\csc(u)\space\text{d}u+\frac{1}{s}=$$
$$\int\csc(u)\space\text{d}u+\frac{1}{\cos(u)}=\int\csc(u)\space\text{d}u+\frac{1}{\cos(\arctan(x))}=$$

---

For the integral $\int\csc(u)\space\text{d}u$, multiply numerator and denominator by $\cot(u)+\csc(u)$:

$$\int\csc(u)\space\text{d}u=\int-\frac{-\cot(u)\csc(u)-\csc^2(u)}{\cot(u)+\csc(u)}\space\text{d}u$$

Now substitute $p=\cot(u)+\csc(u)$ and $\text{d}p=\left(-csc^2(u)-\cot(u)\csc(u)\right)\space\text{d}u$:

$$\int-\frac{1}{p}\space\text{d}p=-\ln\left|p\right|+\text{C}$$

---

$$\frac{1}{\cos(\arctan(x))}-\ln\left|\cot(u)+\csc(u)\right|+\text{C}=$$
$$\frac{1}{\cos(\arctan(x))}-\ln\left|\cot(\arctan(x))+\csc(\arctan(x))\right|+\text{C}=$$
$$\sqrt{1+x^2}-\ln\left|\frac{1}{x}+\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}\right|+\text{C}=$$
$$\sqrt{1+x^2}-\ln\left|\frac{1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}\right|+\text{C}$$

Comment: This is not a ["good" question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Comment: @AnneBauval 7 years later :). But good comment, true.

Answer (score 0):

We can write the integral in a form 
$$J = \int \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}x\,dx = \int \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{1+x^2-1}\,x\,dx $$
which allows the suitable substitution
$$1+x^2=t^2,\quad x\,dx = t\,dt.$$
Then
$$J = \int\frac{t^2}{t^2-1}\,dt = \int dt+\int\frac1{t^2-1}\,dt = t + \frac12\log{\left|\frac{t-1}{t+1}\right|}+C,$$
$$J = \sqrt{1+x^2} + \frac12\log{\left|\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+1}\right|}+C,$$
and after getting rid of irrationality in the denominator:
$$\boxed{J = \sqrt{1+x^2} + \log{\left|\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}x\right|}+C}.$$

Comment: This is not a ["good" question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Comment: @AnneBauval Seven years ago, I was a novice in MSE, and you were not registered there at all. My post had being published before the question was closed. It looks strange to me to find this "actual reaction", which corrupts my reputation. Do you really think that I made an irreparable mistake without a statute of limitations?

Answer (score -1):

Let's put $x=\tan t$.
$$\implies \int \frac {\sqrt{1+x^2}dx}{x}=$$
$$\int \frac{\sec^3 tdt}{\tan t}$$
$$=\int\frac{dt}{\sin t \cos^2 t}$$
$$=\int \frac{(\sin^2t+\cos^2t)dt}{\sin t \cos^2 t}$$
$$=\int \sec t\tan t dt+\int \csc tdt$$
$$=\cdots?$$

Comment: This is not a ["good" question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Comment: @AnneBauval i was 14 when I wrote this answer, it's been 7 years. Get a life.